# Problems with updating the version of an App via Xcode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi I have the following problem.
I am almost finished with creating a new update for my app.
Now I wanted to try if when I install an old version of my app and then run the new version of this app via Xcode on my iPhone.
If the app gets updated correctly to the new version.

Unfortunately this is not the case. I ran into a few problems:

- the icon does not get updated (only looses the shine cause the new
  one does not have on)
- at the start screen of the app there are still parts of the old
  version visible like buttons and labels

most of the app gets updated to the new version correctly.

is this a bug or problem from Xcode or will this be the same when my customers update via Appstore?

Comment: It depends on how you update the app?

Answer (score 1):

This problem won't be there when your customer updates via Apple. I have seen problems like this only during debug.

Comment: This is good news! I hope it is true *keepfingerscrossed*! These problems look really nasty and would be super annoying for the user.